# C# Multiple Locks on list of objects, will I avoid a deadlock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I have a list of 1,000 objects, each of which contain their own LockObject.

I plan on spinning up multiple threads running the same thing. They will pick 6 random objects from the list of 1,000, and then lock on their lock objects. Do something with them before releasing them.

When I create the list of 6 objects I want to work with that cycle, assuming I order the list by some unique value within each object, would the following avoid a deadlock situation between 2 or more such threads?

```
Players = Players.OrderBy(P => P.ID).ToList();

Lock(Players[0].LockObj)
    Lock(Players[1].LockObj)
        Lock(Players[2].LockObj)
            Lock(Players[3].LockObj)
                Lock(Players[4].LockObj)
                    Lock(Players[5].LockObj)
                    {
                        //...
                    }
```

I was reading up on this to try and figure out if this was the "correct" way to write this, it appears that it is, but people gave warning about deadlocks. I believe that this would avoid deadlocks but am not sure 100%.

Comment: You pick things randomly. How do you expect to make a definitive statement of the outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are locking in ascending order then no deadlock is possible. You can prove this by induction.

Not going to show the complete prof but here is the idea.

Given a list of n locks, if you are locking them in ascending order then whatever thread holding lock on lock `n` will always be able to complete since it is the last item and it wouldn't have anything after to wait on.

Since lock n can always complete, lock n-1 can as well since lock n is the only lock n-1 might wait on.

So by induction lock 0-n will always be able to complete and no dead lock is possible.

Comment: For the code provided this is not the case. He is ordering by id first, unless he has other threads that are not ordering by id also attempting to lock multiple objects, at least one thread with the highest locked ID will be able to continue to completion.

Comment: Your example requires item 3 to be taken before item 1, but the question requires all items to be taken in ascending order.  You need to provide an example that involves every single thread taking out all of their items in ascending order to provide a valid counter example.

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, I am sorting them before attempting to lock. They are sorted by ID, which will be unique amongst each object. Would this be enough to prevent a deadlock in itself?

Comment: @Draco he said he is going to pick 6 items at random and lock them. If OP doesn't sort the random items then deadlock is possible. My last line also states that if he sorts the random results first then no deadlock is possible

Comment: @pingu2k4 you need to sort the random result as well. cuz your random result could be 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 10 for example. Sort that then you are good

Comment: @Steve He orders his players by ID in the very first line of code.

Comment: @Draco depends on if the players object is the actual list of 6 nodes or the complete list of 1000 nodes

Comment: @Steve The usage is shown.  There's no reason to guess.

Comment: Players is the list of randomly selected objects, which I then sort by ID and then lock each of them after that. Each object within Players is distinct, and was originally randomly pulled from a larger list of 1000 of such objects.

Comment: @pingu2k4 ok, I have edited the answer to include a simple induction prof

Answer (score -1):

Since you are ordering your list first you shouldn't deadlock, unless another thread tries to lock the same objects out of order from different code.

It's generally a bad idea to lock objects before you actually need them. If you are performing a calculation that requires access to all six objects at once to perform, then it's hard to get around that, but if you are just performing an operation on each of the six objects, you should lock one at a time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    lock(Players[i].LockObj)
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Your current code can degrade significantly if you are using this code from multiple threads. If different threads try to lock the same object you can end up with situations where every thread but one is halted waiting for their turn to go, resulting in slow synchronous behavior.

If you are performing calculations that require access to all six objects, it is preferable to lock them one at a time, copy the information you need, and unlock them. Then do your calculations, again lock them one at a time, copy over your changes, and unlock them.

If your calculations require that the players not change from the state they were in when you copied the data, you can use a tracking variable or hash when doing edits to detect when the data has been edited and then you can choose your strategy for handling this case: Undo changes already made to the other players and recalculate? Accept that you are overwriting changes from another thread? Do some other action?

Comment: There's no problem at all if a given worker tries to lock on the same object multiple times.  There's also no problem with having an item appear in the collection multiple times, so long as the value being ordered on is identical for each copy of the object being locked on, and no other synchronization objects have that same value.

Comment: AH, Monitor is re-entrant. learn something new everyday. I updated my answer.